# Looking for a hash with an output of 50 characters?

Tags: hash, skype

I'm attempting to figure out how Skype stores the emoticons it downloads, and there does seem to be a standard in the naming scheme. All files are prefixed with a code similar to the one below, which is a 50 character hash prefixed and suffixed with a caret character. I have been unable to find any reference to a 50 character / 200 bit hash, although references to SHA-3 did appear in my queries.

```
^2BA3514B75E7AF97940579D1E698B7F33984FE029B2FA59CB3^
```

This hash might be some variation of 'rain', '(rain)' or 'Raining', however I have no way of attempting to reverse-engineer it. If possible, could you point me to a similar or identical algorithm?